# Как вывести значение одного столбца, зная значение другого mySql, php

Tags: php, mysql, вывод

Я вывожу Id одной таблицы и получаю значение 1 или 2 - неважно. Я знаю, что это значение - Id создателя статьи. Вопрос - как мне вывести nickname создателя, зная его id через mysql.
Ответ пожалуйста в одну строчку с нахождением id из таблицы posts и позже, по этому id - nickname в другой таблице users. Условие - id в posts такое же как id в users.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT nickname FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM posts);
```

Почитать подробнее про такие штуки можно тут:
http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/ANSI_diff_Sub-selects.html

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.